# AppEngine: How do I get the sequence of datastore write events?

Tags: google-app-engine

I need a sequencer for the entire application's data.

Using a counter entity is a bad idea (5 writes per second limit), and Sharding counters are not an option.

GMT time stamp seems unsafe due to clock variances with servers, plus a possible server time being set/reset.

Any idea? 
How do I get a entity property which I can query for all entities changed since a given value?

TIA

Comment: what for you need that? ordered sequences aren't suitable for distributed apps

Comment: Thanks splix. I need it for many-to-many data synchronization.

Comment: but why it requires using sequences?

Comment: So each client (Android phone) knows were to start reading for new/updated data. (By sending a read request to AppEngine with the last sequence number read on previous fetch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed datastores such as the app engine datastore don't have a global sequence - there's literally no way to determine if entity A was written to server A' before entity B was written to server B' if those events occur sufficiently close together, unless you have a single machine mediating all transactions and serializing them, which places a hard upper bound on how scalable your system can be.

For your actual practical problem, the easiest solution would be to assign a modification timestamp to each record, and each time you need to sync, look for records newer than (that timestamp) - (epsilon), where epsilon is a short time interval that is longer than the expected difference in time synchronization between servers (something like 10 seconds should be *ample*). Your client can then discard any duplicate records it receives.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thanks again. The issue I have with a timestamp is to get a global trusted source for time. A source such that all App Engine servers can use and get the same (or close enough) time. Are you aware of any simple server-side solution? (I don't like the idea of using NTP on the Android Phone, nor provide my own non-App Engine server that can serve JSON requests from the App Server, since App Engine would not allow direct access to NTP)

Comment: @OfeR Just use the server timestamp. Servers are NTP synced, so as long as you pick a reasonable epsilon this will work fine.

Comment: this is great. I came across a year-old discussion, where it was claimed that the servers are not synced and someone claimed that he once observed 40 mins difference between servers.  I understand that you have been working closely with the AppEngine guys, so would it be fair to say that what you know is the current situation? Apologies for my doubts, but this is obviously very important to me. (BTW does Google state anything officially about this?)  Thanks again. You are a life saver :-)

Comment: @OfeR I'm on the App Engine team, yes. I've heard unsubstantiated reports of ridiculously out-of-sync servers, but never observed it myself, or heard it reliably from any of my oncall colleagues.